# aiogram - How to execute a function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiogram

**Update:**
After few uncessful attempts to explain the problem, completely rewrote the question:

**How to execute a function on startup?**

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'API'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer(message.text)

async def notify_message() # THIS FUNCTION
  # await bot.sendMessage(chat.id, 'Bot Started')
  await print('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   notifty_message() # doesn't work
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

**Tried without success:**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  dp.loop.create_task(notify_message()) # Function to execute
  executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_task'

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.create_task(notify_message()) # Function to execute
  executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than expected. **facepalm**

 Working Solution:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'API'
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
   await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

def test_hi():
   print("Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   test_hi()
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call `aiogram.executor.start(dispatcher, future)` to run an async function (future)

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor

bot = Bot(token='your_api_token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def notify_message() # THIS FUNCTION
  # await bot.sendMessage(chat.id, 'Bot Started')
  await print('Hello World')

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer(message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start(dp, notify_message())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

*I apologize in advance if my English is bad. I don't speak it well)))*

### *It is much easier than you thought)*

Aiogram has built-in tool for this: **on_startup**.
You may create a function that takes a single argument: Dispatcher, and acts the way you need it to. In your case it would like something like this:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'API'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer(message.text)

async def notify_message(dp: Dispatcher) # THIS FUNCTION
  print('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=notify_message)
```

Also you can await your function like this:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'API'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer(message.text)

async def notify_message() # THIS FUNCTION
  # await print('Hello World')
  print('Hello, world') # you shouldn't await the print fucntion, because it isn't async.

if __name__ == '__main__':
   await notifty_message()
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

OR, you can make it not async and simply ask it like this:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'API'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
  await message.answer(message.text)

def notify_message() # THIS FUNCTION
  print('Hello, world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   notifty_message()
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Choose variant which you like more)
If I were you, **I would choose the first**, because it is, as I said before, built-in desicion by aiogram, and you can use some functions as if bot works, such as for examle send admins that bot is turned on.

**P.S.**

You can find more information in aiogram [docs](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/advanced_executor_example.html#id1)

*Something like this answer should have been)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iniate a dialogue, it's impossible, telegram doesn't allow bots to send first message. But if you want to save your users ids, you can make a database or just a txt file and write there any new user id. You will be able to send to all of them messages by inputing id from database instead of `chat.id`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. Sorry for the confusion. Scenario, Bot already initiated, and working. and upon restart, I wanted to send a message to already existing chat id. (eg, my chat.id)

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example of how to send a message without using message.answer just use:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

I don't understand why you need to print ('The bot is running') When running "aiogram" it tells you that the bot was started

```
2021-06-01 09:31:42,729:INFO:Bot: YourBot [@YourBot]
2021-06-01 09:31:42,729:WARNING:Updates were skipped successfully.
2021-06-01 09:31:42,729:INFO:Start polling.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
@dp.message_handler() waits for the user to input a message. Therefore i wanted something that it sends already to existing chat a message.

I can see in the logs that the bot is running, but it was just an example, to send notification over the telegram. In the example i just # the main message, and was asking how to execute a function, though it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach was correct, but asyncio event loop was not initialised. So, if it was important to call async function beside a bot, you would do:

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'API'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot, loop=get_event_loop())  # Initialising event loop for the dispatcher

async def notify_message():
    print('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.loop.create_task(notify_message())  # Providing awaitable as an argument
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```